# The users cannot edit their own password

Tags: users

I installed the Profile2 module, and users cannot change their own password from the edit profile page. The message just says all changes are done, but when I try to log out and log in back, I get an error about the password being wrong.

Comment: It's difficult to tell so I'll ask for some more information. If you disable the module, do you still have this problem? Please also check in the database, if when changing the password, the field "pass" in "users" table is updated.

Comment: I tried to disable module and check DB , the same result , no changes on DB